# Find the projection matrix $P$ onto the column space of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&-6\\
3& 6\\
4 &8\\
5&0 \\
7&8\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I know that $P = A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$. I first found $A^{T}A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &3  &4  &5  &7 \\ 
-6 &  6& 8 & 0 &8 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1&-6\\
3& 6\\
4 &8\\
5&0 \\
7&8\\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
100 &100 \\ 
100 & 100
\end{bmatrix}$

However, when I try to take its inverse, it does not exist? I tried $\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b\\
-c&a
\end{bmatrix}$ and $ad-bc=100-100=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your matrix calculation again. When I tried to calculate $A^TA$, I got 
$$
A^TA =
\begin{bmatrix}
100 &100 \\ 
100 & 200
\end{bmatrix} 
$$